# I need to select an item of a sysListView32 using sendmessage in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, listview, sendmessage

I'm automating meta trader issues. I need to select an item on a syslistview32 (Listview) using sendmessage in C#. Anybody could help me?

Prateek

Comment: Use their APIs if any (And i am not sure if they allow their programs to be automated)

Comment: No, actually they don't. I need to find some solutions using win32 api

Comment: if listview have style LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED you can't get text in that case..because it is painted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ListView messages are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The easiest way is probably using the `LVM_SETITEMSTATE` message. It receives a pointer to a `LVITEM` struct, so it may take some marshalling skills.

The actual fields to be set are actually easy:

- `mask = LVIF_STATE`
- `state = LVIS_SELECTED | LVIS_FOCUSED`
- `stateMask = LVIS_SELECTED | LVIS_FOCUSED`
- `iItem = <the index of the item to be selected>`

That should be enough to select the item you want.

Comment: Could you guide me through some basic marshalling tutorial links? I work on C# though. No MFC experience.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any good tutorials, although there are plenty of information in the net. You can find many already done marshalls in   the [pinvoke](http://http://www.pinvoke.net/) site, but unfortunately not the one you need.